# Is it possible to invoke a device calendar to add event using phone gap?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have been searching for this for the past two days, Through phoneGap concept i need to fetch a device calendar to add an event or reminders. It should work on all devices through Phone Gap. but i could not able to reach the solution properly.. Please guide me with a proper link or suggest me some examples with steps.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the CalendarPlugin for Phonegap. A list of plugins is available in https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about android but on ios you can access the native date picker by creating an input field with the type="date".